# Error in the systemtap script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, systemtap

I am trying to execute a systemtap script. But during execution i got the following semantic error.

```
stap -v -g netfilter.stp 
Pass 1: parsed user script and 96 library script(s) using 150164virt/25896res/2100shr/24504data kb, in 230usr/20sys/243real ms.
WARNING: Eliding unused function '__get_mac_addr': identifier '__get_mac_addr' at netfilter.stp:26:10
 source: function __get_mac_addr:string(addr:long) {
                  ^
WARNING: Eliding unused function '__get_skb_arphdr': identifier '__get_skb_arphdr' at :37:10
 source: function __get_skb_arphdr:long(addr:long)
                  ^
WARNING: Eliding unused function '__ip6_skb_proto': identifier '__ip6_skb_proto' at :43:10
 source: function __ip6_skb_proto:long(addr:long)
                  ^


**semantic error: no probes found**


Pass 2: analyzed script: 0 probe(s), 0 function(s), 2 embed(s), 0 global(s) using 352168virt/98268res/3352shr/95492data kb, in 950usr/250sys/2047real ms.
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
```

Help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you're trying to run a tapset .stp file (which is a library of reusable parts, like libc), instead of a script that actually contains probes & work to do.  See the `netfilter_drop.stp` and `netfilter_summary.stp` files for some sample usage.